showing that $\partial^2=0$ in the nerve of a lie groupoid.
I want t prove that $\partial^2=0$ where the map
$\partial$ is defined for every $\omega \in \Omega^{p}(\mathcal{G}_p)$ as
$$\partial(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{p+2} (-1)^i (\partial_i)^* \omega \in \Omega^p(\mathcal{G}_{p+1})$$
(Here $\mathcal{G}_1\to \mathcal{G}_0)$ is a lie groupoid and $\mathcal{G}_p$ is the sequence of p componible.), can someone help me with that?
I was trying to do a particular case where $\omega\in\Omega^k(\mathcal{G}_0)$, so, in this case, we have that $\partial \omega =s^* \omega -t^* \omega $, then
$$\partial^2 \omega=\partial (s^* \omega - t^* \omega )=(pr_1^* - m^* + pr^*_2)(s^* \omega - t^* \omega )=pr_1^* (s^* \omega ) - m^* (s^* \omega ) + pr_2^* (s^* \omega )$$.
But I did not get it.
